# How to get html content of several descendants within a specific range?

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a layout like this:

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div>content 1</div>
    <div>content 2</div>
    ...
    <div>content n
        <div>sub-content</div>
    </div>
    <div>content n+1</div>
    ... 
    <div>content m</div>
    ...
    <div>content N</div>
</div>
```

I need to get the html content from content 'n' to 'm' included the subcontent (if it exists), i.d.:

```
<div>content n
    <div>sub-content</div>
</div>
<div>content n+1</div>
... 
<div>content m</div>
```

I tried to use the find- and slice-function but I got problems if sub-contents exist (below my attempt for getting the content from '1' to 'm')

```
var index = $('#parent').find('p:contains("content m")').index();
var cont = $('#parent').children().slice(0,index+1).html();
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Can't you rely on their position in the parent? And use `$('#parent > *').eq(index)` ?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: @andrei: No, I can't. The position of 'subcontent' is dynamic

Comment: @gerfried: yes, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve with this, but here is a sample which should work:

https://plnkr.co/edit/nJ9Gj89mP5RJyXplWr9C

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var inScope = false;
  var result = '';
  $("div#parent").find("div").each(function(k, v) {
    if(!inScope && $(v).html().indexOf('content n') >= 0) {
      inScope = true;
    }
    if(inScope) {
      console.log($(v));
      result += $(v)[0].outerHTML;
    }
    if(inScope && $(v).html().indexOf('content m') >= 0) {
      inScope = false;
    }    
  })
  console.log(result);
});
```